# Remove autorotating from PostScript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript

I have the following PostScript (stamp.ps) to add a watermark to a PDF file:

```
<<
   /EndPage
   {
     2 eq { pop false }
     {
         gsave      
         /Helvetica_Bold 24 selectfont
         130 70 moveto (Sample) show
         grestore
         true
     } ifelse
   } bind
>> setpagedevice
```

I call it like this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf stamp.ps -f in.pdf
```

and it works alright, except sometimes it rotates the PDF. To prevent that, I added `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`, so now I call it like this:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
   -sOutputFile=out.pdf stamp.ps -f in.pdf
```

But now it sometimes rotates the watermark text (for the files which were previously rotated).

My question is: how do I stop rotating both text and pages.

Comment: FYI, you can use `-o out.pdf` instead of `-sOutputFile=out.pdf`.

Comment: FYI, the much shorter single `-o out.pdf` replaces all these *three* params at once: `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=out.pdf`...

Answer (score 1):

If you set `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` then Ghostscript will not rotate the page (please note for other people reading this, this switch **only** affects the `pdfwrite` device).

Ghostscript will never rotate the text in your `EndPage` procedure. Which means something else is going on and there's no way to tell what it is without an example.